# Can I create a signature in the contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, signature, solidity-0.8.x

I can use the function ecrecover to verify a signature in the contract, but I want to know how to create a
signature in the contract. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

You cannot.

**Better answer**

You shouldn't want to.

There is a two-fold engineering dilemma.

1. The computationally-heavy work of creating a signature isn't well-suited to a platform where cost is proportional to work. There are workarounds, but ...
2. Anything a contract can do is replicable by everyone else. For example, the whole idea of a signature is that it *proves knowledge* of a secret only the signer should know - the private key. For a contract to perform this process, the contract would have to *know the secret*. If that is the case, then *everyone knows the secret* which renders a signature meaningless.

**They don't need to**

In most cases, what you want is to show that an action came from the contract. This is handled at a protocol level without the need for the contract to sign anything.

I might suggest reframing the question in terms of what needs to be proven because it's probably doable. The solution will not include the contract signing in the way that externally-owned accounts do it.

Hope it helps.